# Having Trouble Importing Image into Project

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I'm trying to import a few images into my project and I'm having trouble doing so. Drag and Drop makes the image a text file filled with seemingly random symbols.

All images are PNG. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is my project folder so you can see what I'm talking about:
[image: workspace]

And here are the random symbols:
[randomSymbols http://s3.postimg.org/ithy6spoh/randommm.png](http://s3.postimg.org/ithy6spoh/randommm.png)

Comment: You have to provide more details about what your problem is. What do you  mean by import? And import to where? Are you talking about placing an image file inside a folder in an eclipse/netbeans project? When you say "random symbols" are you trying to open a binary file (image) with a text editor?

Comment: Updated post with images of my Eclipse screen. Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm seeing correctly, you're trying to open an image file with Eclipse's text-editor. The editor will show you the binary content of the image (the random symbols).

There's nothing wrong with your files. If you right click on an image and choose "open with" -> "System editor" it will show the images in your OS's default image viewer. And the image will be ok.

Comment: So if I use this images with a JLabel, it should load as an image. Right?

Comment: Sure, provided the path you pass to load the image is correct, it should load fine.